# Is there any way to get SIZE of the screen in tvOS?

Tags: swift, size, screen, tvos, tvos9.1

I am trying to get size the of the screen connected to apple tv, is it possible?
I have been looking into the documentation provided by apple related to UIScreen but couldn't find anything new except nativeBounds which is same as bounds.

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
let nativeBound = UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.size
```

Both of them are giving me output in pixels, but i need the screen/monitor size (inch) as well. So that i could arrange the display accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` returns the size of the screen in points, not pixels. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds).

`UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds` returns the screen size in pixels.

To find the actual screen size (in an absolute unit of size such as inches), you would need to know the physical size of a pixel, and multiply that by the `nativeBounds`.

**However, I don't think iOS has an API to retrieve pixel size.**

Comment: So that is the particular point i am looking for screenSizeInPixels can be found through let nativeBound = UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.size.

Comment: True. `nativeBounds` returns the size in pixels, which saves you from doing the calculation. I'll update my answer.